# Firebase App not getting initialised in EC2 instance

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-admin

I'm using firebase-admin sdk to send push notifications to our android application.

I have downloaded the credentials json and set it as an environment variable on our ec2 instance.

But when the application starts, I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute
>   Engine.
>
> The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are
>   available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the
>   environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined
>   pointing to a file defining the credentials.

For setting the environment variable, I have added it in the **.bash_profile** file.

Here is the code to initialise the firebase app:

```
FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = FirebaseOptions.builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault())
            .setDatabaseUrl(FIREBASE_DB_URL)
            .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(firebaseOptions, FIREBASE_APP_NAME);
```

Comment: Are you actually running the application from bash? It looks like the env variable is not visible to your application process for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that your `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable is actually pointing at the file you downloaded, at the point when your application is run, and that the file is readable by your application.

That said, you can use the file in a different way that is less sensitive to the environment you are in, which is likely going to be more reliable:

Instead of using the default credentials approach, though, you can also just use the key file directly in your code, like this (this code is just directly copied from the [Service Accounts page](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk) page where the key is generated, make sure to set the database url correctly for your app):

```java
FileInputStream serviceAccount =
  new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
  .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
  .setDatabaseUrl("https://your-project-name.firebaseio.com")
  .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

Assuming the path is set correctly and the key is deployed with your app, this should work regardless of the environment (OS, shell, etc).

Comment: I have verified that the env variable ```GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS``` is set and is pointing to the credentials file. Everything runs fine on my local machine but for some reason, the application is unable to read the variable it on the ec2 instance.
For now, I'm using the ```fromStream``` approach.